# Ajax object comes back empty

Tags: ajax

I'm writing a plugin with an ajax request and I'm getting a weird problem. It works fine the first few times but then all of a sudden, the data ends up empty or NULL.

This is the code:

```
/* in functions.php */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_rs-MYajaxAction', 'wpw_display_js_vars');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_rs-MYajaxAction', 'wpw_display_js_vars');

function wpw_display_js_vars() {
    var_dump($_POST['uid']);
    //outputs null
    die();
}
```

And:

```
/* p_name, user_meta.current_user_id, clicked_post and ajaxurl 
 * are all global defined in another part of the script 
 */
$('.walkthrough-list').find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {
                action: "rs-MYajaxAction",
                p: p_name, 
                uid : user_meta.current_user_id,
                tut_name : clicked_post
            },
            function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
        });// end $.post 
        return false;
});
```

<sup>[As a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pencilking2002/Vgfrn/2/)</sup>

Is there any reason why data gets "lost" when its posted to `admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: Do you have any Javascript errors?

Comment: No, the data is there but when posted to admin-ajax.php, by the time it gets there, the objects are null!

Comment: But you say it works a few times? Sounds like an intermittent server timeout but it is going to be very hard to debug from the outside, so to speak. Do have access to server logs? If so, try to match up requests to `admin-ajax.php` with your failures.

Comment: I am using it on MAMP locally right now, the logs you are talking about would be the apache log?

Comment: The Apache, the MySQL, and the PHP logs in reverse order of "likely to be helpful".

Comment: Read [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), then enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG so you can get a log of errors in wp-content/debug.log

Comment: Is this actually a **WordPress**-specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stackoverflow answer has a good example of basic ajax posting.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example

I would try adjusting your code so that the info you want to post is in the `data` parameter.  jQuery isn't my strongest suit, but I was under the impression that the $_POST data came through that parameter.

```
$('.walkthrough-list').find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {

        data = 'p='+p_name+&uid='+user_meta.current_user_id+'&tut_name='+clicked_post;
        $.post(
            ajaxurl,
            {
                action: "rs-MYajaxAction",
                data: data
            },
            function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
        });// end $.post 
        return false;
});
```

Granted there is probably a much better way to serialize your data.